# Fire jQuery scroll event only once

Tags: jquery

I want to fire an jQuery scroll event only once, it works but when I have a new scroll event it doesn't work hope someone can help me.

```
$(".content").scroll(function(){ 
    if(var == 1) {
        $(".content").off("scroll");
        console.log("it works only once");
    }
}

$(".content").on("scroll", function() {
    console.log("This should work always, but it don't work");
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might might to check out the documentation for `.one()` http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Are you having more than one elements with `.content` class??

Comment: yes you should use `.one()` for the first, if you keep using that code, you have to specify exactly the handler you want to `off` it, without specifying what should be applied by `off`, all the handlers (including the second handler) will be removed. (then it won't work).

Comment: Use namespace to on/off the event.

Comment: I have tried .one() but it doesn't work with the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see it, you should use namespaced event:

```
$(".content").on("scroll.custom", function(){ 
    if(someVariableCheck == 1) {
        $(".content").off("scroll.custom");
        console.log("it works only once");
    }
}

$(".content").on("scroll", function() {
    console.log("This should work always, but it don't work");
});
```

You could use `one` to bind specific handler to be fired only once but this would be unregarding variable check.